# Remove property in Realm object

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I'm trying to remove a property in one of my Realm objects however I'm not sure how to write a migration for this.

I just removed the property from my object's header file but that didn't work as I get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason:
>   'Migration is required for object type 'Stock' due to the following
>   errors:
>   - Property 'percentageOn' is missing from latest object model.'

I know how to write a migration add fields, but how do I remove one?

Comment: Of course you are not able to do it directly without the consequence. Solution 1: Remove the property like U did and remove the app from the simulator. This solves the issue with DB inconsistency. Solution 2: Your app is in production and users already use it. So U need to perform the migration to not to affect your customers. And please read the doc what to do in such case: https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#migrations

Answer (score 9):

What David said is correct. If you make sure to perform a migration properly, then Realm can easily handle properties that have been removed as well as added. Unless you actually still need the value in `percentageOn`, you can even leave the migration block empty like in the example on the Realm website:

```
// Inside your [AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]

// Notice setSchemaVersion is set to 1, this is always set manually. It must be
// higher than the previous version (oldSchemaVersion) or an RLMException is thrown
[RLMRealm setSchemaVersion:1
            forRealmAtPath:[RLMRealm defaultRealmPath] 
        withMigrationBlock:^(RLMMigration *migration, NSUInteger oldSchemaVersion) {
  // We haven’t migrated anything yet, so oldSchemaVersion == 0
  if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
    // Nothing to do!
    // Realm will automatically detect new properties and removed properties
    // And will update the schema on disk automatically
  }
}];

// now that we have called `setSchemaVersion:withMigrationBlock:`, opening an outdated
// Realm will automatically perform the migration and opening the Realm will succeed
[RLMRealm defaultRealm];
```

Comment: Ok so inside a migration block Realm checks for any removed properties and removes them from the DB?

Comment: Correct! That being said, the data in those properties will be deleted as well, so if you need to preserve that data, make sure to move it to a new property in the migration block.